# VS2008 program built in Debug mode crashes but does not in Release mode

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crash

I have a program that builds fine in Debug mode, but crashes upon start of the program without any errors being provided. However, this program, when built in Release mode, runs perfectly.

However, the program does crash from time to time when running in Release mode, but it will always start up fine. So there is something wrong.

I don't know what else to add because I really have no idea and was wondering if you folks could provide any ideas at all.

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah. You could have a look at your source code. With or without memory checking tools. We sure can't

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bad build. Perhaps:

1. Mixing debug / release dlls
2. Incorrect project settings for whether to statically or dynamically link with the runtime library.
3. Mixxing single / multi threaded versions of the runtime.
4. Incorrect 32-bit / 64-bit settings, causing a mismatch between the exe and dlls.